# Trying to get a sidebar to the left side and main content after it

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I am trying to get a sidebar to the left side while the main content is right after it. Right now the main content is on the left and the sidebar to the right. Both are floated to the left but the main content is first. I want the sidebar to be first.

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vzk8hqrq/

```
<section class="first_article">
    <article>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
        <p>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</p>
        <img src="cupcake.jpg" alt="cupcake" class="cupcake">
    </article>
</section>

<aside class="sidebar">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>about us</li>
            <li>orders</li>
            <li>gallery</li>
            <li>contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</aside>



.first_article{
float:left;
border:1px solid black;
width:500px;
}

.sidebar{
float:left;
}
```

Comment: Is this you are looking at http://jsfiddle.net/vzk8hqrq/1/

Comment: make .first_article to float:right

Comment: I know that i can float it right but then there is a lot of space in between them.

Comment: Have you check http://jsfiddle.net/vzk8hqrq/1/

Comment: jatin how did you do that?I cant seem to find any difference in the code but that is what i want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Changed this:  Brought `<aside class="sidebar">` before `<section class="first_article">`

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vzk8hqrq/1/)

```
<aside class="sidebar">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>about us</li>
            <li>orders</li>
            <li>gallery</li>
            <li>contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</aside>

<section class="first_article">
    <article>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
        <p>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</p>
        <img src="cupcake.jpg" alt="cupcake" class="cupcake">
    </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you set the content's `float` attribute to `right`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add float:right on first_article

```
.first_article {
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: right;
    width: 500px;
}
```

If you on firefox, use [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/). Its very powerfull developer tools

Answer (score 0):

add float right

```
.first_article{
float:right;
border:1px solid black;
width:500px;
}
```